# What is an affix called that is interlocked?

Tags: syntax, terminology, morphology, affixes

Wikipedia mentions 4 subgroups of affixes:

- prefix, the affix is in front of the word
- suffix, the affix is behind the word
- infix, the affix is within the word
- circumfix, the afix is separated into two parts, before and after the word

Now, in Arabic, the derivation of words is based on roots and patterns, to form a real word one has to combine the  root and pattern, so that they are interlocked.

Similar to this, in Chinese one can combine, for instance,  起来 and 请客 by interlocking them into: 请起客来.

How is this kind of affixation called ?

Comment: Normally linguists call this a "Semitic lexical system", since it's common in the Afro-Asiatic family (which includes the Semitic subfamily, which contains prominent examples of Semitic lexical systems). It's a sort of evolved root system; many synthetic and polysynthetic languages have simple roots ([Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html) words normally have `CVC` roots, though the words are normally much longer, from inflections and derivations). In Semitic systems, the root has been abstracted to consonants, and the inflections involve the vowels, plus affixes.

Comment: @jlawler. If affix means prefix + suffix + infix I do not see the point of counting the vowels as separate inflectional elements. Why can't we call the vowels in (for example) Arabic kutub "infixes"?

Comment: Feel free to do so. But note that it's a compound infix: _-u-u-_, as is _-i-a-_

Comment: Or two infixes.

Comment: i am not an expert, but would not two infixes be bound each one to a single grammatical category, whereas a "transfix" is bound to one and looses it once cut into smaller phonetic units?

Comment: In a word like šajar, plural ʼašjār ‘trees’, the plural is expressed by the combination of two morphemes: a prefix and an infix. So I would think that in kitāb, plural kutub ‘books’ the plural is expressed by two infixes. At least this seems the most economical analysis.

Comment: This is known as [template morphology](http://www2.let.uu.nl/uil-ots/lexicon/zoek.pl?lemma=Template+morphology)

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut You claimed that at several occasions on SE. Template morphology is actually associated with polysynthetic languages (Athapaskan, Bantu-II, etc.). Semitic languages are not in that sense polysynthetic.

Comment: I've come across the idea of template morphology mostly in relation to agglutinative languages such as Basque and Georgian. I haven't had the opportunity to study a polysynthetic language.

Comment: @ThomasGross Whether it strictly should be or not, I've heard it called template morphology too.

Comment: @curiousdannii Templates are slots within, mostly, the verb into which material is inserted that references grammatical roles (subject, object, etc, and sometimes adverbials). I only know Hebrew, but I can say with a certain degree of confidence that no pattern(as in root-and-pattern morphology)/transfix in Hebrew references grammatical categories such as the ones I mention above. In Biblical Hebrew and written Modern Hebrew, one can find object **suf**fixes, such as *li-fogš-o* [inf-meet-3sg.m.obj] 'to meet him', but these are suffixes, rather than patterns or transfixes.

Comment: @ThomasGross I think you're confusing 'verbal template' (a representation of the verb as a series of slots into which particular roots and affixes may be placed) with 'template morphology', which refers to the nonconcatenative, prosodic 'root and pattern' morphology that is found in (e.g.) Semitic languages. (cont...)

Comment: (...) For a general discussion, see Section 12.2 of the [Oxford Handbook of Derivational Morphology](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=If2KBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=template+morphology+semitic+mccarthy&source=bl&ots=uIJfA8VDwm&sig=tZ810RsRGrA6RJaP02y4Lg1lzQU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LEF2VNTvJseMmwWwlYCQDQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false). For detailed analysis see anything by McCarthy and Prince on prosodic morphology in Arabic ([eg this](http://people.umass.edu/jjmccart/template.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

[Semitic root-and-pattern morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_root) can be called [transfixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfix) or [templatic morphology](http://www2.let.uu.nl/uil-ots/lexicon/zoek.pl?lemma=Template%20morphology), but in the morphological literature you're perhaps more likely to find the terms *[non-concatenative morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonconcatenative_morphology)* or *discontinuous morphology,* which would include transfixation as well as other processes such as [reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) and morphologically conditioned segmental (e.g., [ablaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony)) or non-segmental (e.g., tonal) changes.

Some prominent theoretical analyses of non-concatenative morphological processes include Prosodic Morphology ([McCarthy & Prince 1995](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/b.9780631201267.1996.00011.x)) and A-Morphous Morphology ([Anderson 1992](https://books.google.com/books?id=UT1R55Bj-yIC&lpg=PP1&dq=a-morphous%20morphology&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)); Anderson goes so far as to question the theoretical status of the morpheme on the basis of patterns of this type.

Answer (score 1):

These affixes are called [**transfixes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfix).

Comment: I am not convinced that "transfix" is a useful concept. By the way, in the glorious Wikipedia article to which you have linked every one of the Arabic examples is wrong.

Comment: What makes you question that "transfix" is  a useful concept?

Comment: @fdb In what way are the Arabic examples wrong? Are they wrongly translated? If so, you can easily edit the respective examples. Or do you mean that the boldface vowels aren't transfixes? And in what way could the term "transfix" be not useful? It's just a name for a certain class of phenomena.

Comment: They are misspelt and wrongly translated. For example it is not daraba “to beat” but ḍaraba (with emphatic ḍ) “he beat”. I am not exaggerating: every single example is wrong.

Comment: As for me editing them, honestly I prefer to write my own books rather than playing around with some anonymous and ephemeral web-site.

Comment: ok, that s orthography, but what about the usefullness of the concept of transfixes?

Comment: I am not talking about orthography, but about erroneous interpretation of both phonology and morphology. As for “transfixes” kindly look at my exchange of views with @jlawler, above.

Comment: your first sentence here was "I am not convinced that "transfix" is a useful concept" <-- that is what i am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You might want **not** to call this an affix. This is Templatic Morphology as opposed to Affixal Morphology as suggested by [Jason Zentz](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/6753/jason-zentz) [above](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/9812/7998).